# Change the tmp folder of firefox?

Tags: firefox

I checked `about:config`, but I didn't find anything related to the temporary folder.

By default, when you choose to open a file instead of save it, it would download the file to `/tmp', and open it when completed, now I'd like to pick another location.

Already tried to add `browser.cache.disk.parent_directory`, but that doesn't seem to work for 16.0.2

Comment: Hello warl0ck, Did you use the string "browser.cache.disk.parent_directory"..? in the `about:config`

Comment: @CrazyBuddy Hmm, I don't have that entry, only some "size" or "enable" stuff

Comment: @CrazyBuddy let me see if it works by creating one

Comment: Yes, it works if you create a new string...

Comment: @CrazyBuddy hmm, no luck, I restarted firefox, and it still uses `/tmp`

Comment: Have you checked whether the string "browser.cache.disk.enable" is true?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6439/discussion-between-warl0ck-and-crazy-buddy)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy that actually worked ... you can put it as an answer ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new preference `browser.cache.disk.parent_directory` in `about:config` and use the value `<Location>` indicating the location you required. Then, make sure that you've toggled the `browser.cache.disk.enable` to TRUE value.

Hope that helps...